# Finding the center of these pictures, OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the exact center of these attached images. The things I've tried:

1- HoughCircles, but it didn't work because it's not a perfect circle...

2- Thresholded the picture, so it's all black and white -> contour -> center of contour. This doesn't work on both of these images. It gives a center which isn't correct.

Does one of you know another approach I can try?

EDIT: In the first image, you can see why just taking the center with the contour doesn't work. It's not perfectly in the center of the 'circle'

EDIT2: The definition of the center can be seen in the second image where the circle touches all the 'sides' at the same moment

Thanks,

[image: Why the contour doesn't work]
[image: How it should be]
[image] [image]

Comment: Try convex hull on the contour https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html

Comment: @frab, okay thanks, I will try Convex Hull, but it might not work on the last image, because the contour won't be symmetrical

Comment: please define "the exact center" more precisely. If it is not "definable", you may need a statistical definition based on a data set.

Comment: Have you considered marking it on the object before filming it?

Comment: @Gulzar, the definition of the center --> see the 2nd picture. It's where a circle touches more than 50% of the sides at once.
@ Mark Setchell, that's not possible unfortunately

Comment: Maybe try calculating the distance transform of your masked image and the brightest pixel is the furthest from the mask's edges - if that is your *"centre"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Threshold the image using the OTSU-Method (which will leave you with a binary image, where only the middle section should be kept. Maybe you have to modify the actual threshold value a little bit)
2. On the thresholded image find the center using image moments (see e.g. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d49/tutorial_moments.html)

This assumes, that the middle section will always be brighter in comparison to the area outside.

Comment: Yes I tried this a few minutes ago, but the given center is still offcenter.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could try:

1. [Find corners](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)
2. [Clean up outliers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html)
3. [Average their locations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

I expect that to be quite in the center.

If not, please define the question more precisely.